# How to show that this (given) model of internal energy for a crystalline solid obeys the Third Law of Thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics

I have a model of internal energy for a crystalline solid ($A, b, v_0$ are constants):

[image: A model internal energy, U(S; V;N), for a crystalline solid]

I would like to show that the model obeys the Third Law of Thermodynamics. 
I understand the third law, at a basic level, is that $S$ (entropy) $= 0$ at $T = 0K$ and that $C_V$ goes to zero as $T$ goes to zero.
Please assist. Thank you very much!

Comment: I see that $U = 0$ when $S = 0$. Perhaps it does have something to do with that?